# Get Value from view to controller

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I need to assign value from from view to model and from model to controller.
I am new to MVC and i dont know how can i pass those values.

MODEL- public gulb StringValue {get;set;}

```
view -     
 $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/ValidateMembership",
            type: 'GET',
            data: { StudentDOB: StudentDOB, ssn: ssn },
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function (result) {

                var deserializedResult = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(result));

   if (deserializedResult.StatusCode == 1) {
                    memberFoundCurrent();
       Model.StringValue = deserializedResult.ContactId;
}
      }
        });
```

controller :- needValue = StringValue.

I am not able to store value to Model.Stringvalue, it throws an error. How am i suppose to store the value to Model so that i can use it on controller needvalue

Answer (score 1):

We can easily pass a value from view to controller. Try the following, I changed little bit as per the above

view -

```
var student =  {};     //for ex: student is your model name
student. StringValue = “some value” 
 $.ajax({
     url: "/Home/ValidateMembership",
     type: 'GET',
     data: '{student: ' + JSON.stringify(student) + '}',
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (result) {
        var deserializedResult = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(result));

        if (deserializedResult.StatusCode == 1) {
           memberFoundCurrent();
           Model.StringValue = deserializedResult.ContactId;
        }
      }
   });
```

**Also refer to this link**: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Pass-Send-Model-object-in-jQuery-ajax-POST-request-to-Controller-method-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx

It will give  you detailed idea. Hope it was useful  kindly let me know your thoughts or feedback.

Thanks

Karthik